# Parameter 0 of constructor in com.demo.service.NmpAppService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, jpa, autowired

I am trying to run a simple api flow in java spring and I am getting the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.nmp.bts.webapps.bsc.btbsc.service.NmpAppService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.> 
<Oct 25, 2019 10:37:51 AM EEST> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.> 
<Oct 25, 2019 10:37:51 AM EEST> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.> 
<Oct 25, 2019 10:37:51 AM EEST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "48455312047066616" for task "216" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:237)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:232)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I want to mention that I`ve tried all kind of stuffs starting from the other similar topics on stackoverflow, to change dependency and nothing worked for me.

Controller class: NmpAppController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class NmpAppController {

    private final NmpAppService nmpAppService;

    @Autowired
    public NmpAppController(NmpAppService nmpAppService) {
        this.nmpAppService = nmpAppService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/nmp-apps")
    public List<NmpApp> getAllNmps() {
        try {
            return nmpAppService.getAllNmpApps();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Service class: NmpAppService.java

```
@Service
public class NmpAppService {

    private final NmpAppRepository nmpAppRepository;

    public NmpAppService(NmpAppRepository nmpAppRepository) {
        this.nmpAppRepository = nmpAppRepository;
    }

    public NmpApp save(final NmpApp nmpApp) {

        final NmpApp nmpAppToBeSaved = nmpApp;
        NmpApp result = nmpAppRepository.saveAndFlush(nmpAppToBeSaved);
        return result;
    }

    public NmpApp update(final NmpApp nmpApp) {

        final NmpApp nmpAppitToBeSaved = nmpApp;
        NmpApp result = nmpAppRepository.saveAndFlush(nmpAppToBeSaved);
        return result;
    }

    public List<NmpApp> getAllNmpApps() {
        return nmpAppRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Repository class: NmpAppRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface NmpAppRepository extends JpaRepository<NmpApp, Long> {

}
```

Domain class NmpApp.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NMP_APP")
public class NmpApp {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SEQ_NO")
    private Long seqNo;

    @Column(name = "HIST_DATE")
    private Long histDate;

    public NmpApp() {
    }

    public NmpApp(Long seqNo, Long histDate) {
    this.seqNo = seqNo;
    this.histDate = histDate;
    }

    public Long getSeqNo() {
        return seqNo;
    }

    public void setSeqNo(Long seqNo) {
        this.seqNo = seqNo;
    }

    public Long getHistDate() {
        return histDate;
    }

    public void setHistDate(Long histDate) {
        this.histDate = histDate;
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.nmp.bts.webapps.bsc</groupId>
    <artifactId>nm-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bt-bsc</name>
    <description>BSC</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Spring boot main class: Application.java

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setHttpOnly(false);
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

}
```

Later Edit: I uploaded the application.properties file

```
#Basic Spring Boot Config for Oracle
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:oracle:thin:@//:/
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/DEV_ADF_APPLDS
#hibernate config
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

I want to be able to perform simple CRUD operations on a database via swagger api caller (code shows only getAll but I do have the rest of code tho).

Comment: You need JPA but are excluding the JPA auto configuration.

Comment: can you  please be more precise ?

Comment: You are excluding the `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` so excluding JPA but want to use JPA.

Comment: so now I`m getting ```org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V```

Comment: Remove the `war` plugin from the `pom.xml` Spring Boot takes care of that, as well as the `servlet-api` dependency that is added through the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency already. The `@EnableTransactionManagent` isn't needed as Spring Boot already adds that. When deploying to Weblogic make sure you also add a web logic deployment descriptor to configure class loading (else it might pick the Spring shipped with Weblogic instead of from your own application). Finally is this really the `pom.xml` you are using or is there more in the real `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually happens when Spring is missing the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` since Spring infers the EntityManager from the `Spring Data JPA` which has an out of the box implementation for `Hibernate ORM`.
Adding the following to project `pom.xml` usually solves this problem

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But in your case is available so the offending code is

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Change to

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of spring-boot-starter-data-rest, try using the following

```
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc"
```

Later edit: Also, don't forget to add @EnableTransactionManagement on the spring boot main class or on the database configuration class

Comment: Later edit response: I uploaded the spring boot class annotated as you said but I`m still facing the same error

Comment: any sugestion @Deinum?

Comment: Check out the answer I posted above. This should solve your problem